# Python 3.9 parse and filter json to have entire rows having specific keyword:value

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

For a JSON file, on doing **json.load** its getting converted into **list of dictionaries**.
sample rows are from list of dictionaries are as below: -

```
config_items_list = [{'hostname': '"abc2164"', 'Status': '"InUse"', 'source': '"excel"', 'port': '"[445]"', 'tech': '"Others"', 'ID': '"123456"'}, 
{'hostname': '"xyz2164"', 'Status': '"InUse"', 'source': '"web"', 'port': '"[123]"', 'tech': '"Others"', 'ID': '"456789"'}, 
{'hostname': '"pqr2164"', 'Status': '"NotInUse"', 'source': '"web"', 'port': '"[777]"', 'tech': '"Others"', 'ID': '"123456"'}]
```

Requirement is to parse this list of dictionaries and extract all rows having specific value in **ID** key. For example, 123456 (means two rows from above sample).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the below solution, it searches for the `id_value` even if the `id_value` is surrounded by any symbol or any other number/character as well:

```
expectedResult = [d for d in config_items_list if "123456" in d['ApplicationInstanceID']]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this solution it should solve your problem

```
def filter_json_with_id(config_items_list, id):
    items = []
    for item in config_items_list:
        if item['ID'] == id:
            items.append(item)
    return items
```

Comment: [`id()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) is a Python built-in function, and shouldn't be used as a variable name.

Answer (score 0):

```py
select_id = '"123456"'
[d for d in config_items_list if d["ID"] == select_id]
```

will produce a list with those dictionaries that have given `select_id` as `"ID"` in `config_items_list`.